# Safari 6 and 3d transformations

Tags: javascript, safari, impress.js

So I have a website at [danzimm.com](https://danzimm.com/#/hello) and it worked properly in Safari 5, works properly in Google Chrome and Firefox but no longer works for Safari 6.

I'm using an old version of the impress.js framework (one that I modified a little bit) and I rely on the `rotateX/rotateY/rotateZ` selectors (not sure I'm using the right term there) as well as the `perspective` `translate3d` and `size` selectors (again not sure using the right term)

I am by no means a seasoned web developer but i have touched my nose in a little...

Anyways, is this a bug with Safari 6 or am I doing something silly?

Comment: Personally, I have noticed that Safari 6 is buggy (crashes, freezes, weird UI bugs).  I think that apple should release an update that will fix these bugs (I hope, at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of documented problems with Safari 6 and 3d transforms. Hopefully it will be fixed in the next release. 
[Example 1](http://www.flickr.com/photos/christopherholland/7661336160/)
[Example 2](http://twitter.com/zachleat/status/237244110950522880/photo/1/large)

**Update:** Seems to be fixed in Safari 6.0.1